# Updating Query In URL With Urlib In Python

Tags: python, regex, hash

I have a url that is being parsed out of an XML file.

```
product_url = urlparse(item.find('product_url').text)
```

When I use `urlib` to break the url up I get this,

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/dynamic', params='', query='t=MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN&p=11111111', fragment='')
```

I need to update the

`MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN` part of the query with a MD5 Hashed Oauth Key.

Which I have in this `tokenHashed = encryptMd5Hash(token)`

My goal is to after it is parsed and the hash has been inserted to the string in place of the `MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN`, to have the whole url in a string I can use somewhere else. Originally I was trying to use regex to do this but found urlib. I cannot find where it says to do something like this?

Am I right to be using urlib for this? How do I achieve my goal of updating the url with the hashed token and having the whole url stored in a string?

So the string should look like this,

`newString = 'http://example.com/dynamic?t='+tokenHashed+'&p=11112311312`'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first want to use the `parse_qs` function to  parse the query string into a dictionary:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> import urllib
>>> url = 'http://example.com/dynamic?t=MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN&p=11111111'
>>> parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/dynamic', params='', query='t=MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN&p=11111111', fragment='')
>>> qs = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
>>> qs
{'p': ['11111111'], 't': ['MD5-YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN']}
>>>
```

Now you can modify the dictionary as desired:

```
>>> qs['t'] = ['tokenHashed']
```

Note here that because the `parse_qs` returned lists for each query
parameter, we need replace them with lists because we'll be calling
`urlencode` next with `doseq=1` to handle those lists.

Next, rebuild the query string:

```
>>> newqs = urllib.urlencode(qs, doseq=1)
>>> newqs
'p=11111111&t=tokenHashed'
```

And then reassemble the URL:

```
>>> newurl = urlparse.urlunparse(
... [newqs if i == 4 else x for i,x in enumerate(parsed)])
>>> newurl
'http://example.com/dynamic?p=11111111&t=tokenHashed'
```

That list comprehension there is just using all the values from
`parsed` except for item 4, which we are replacing with our new query
string.

Comment: Also, I'm using Python 2.  If you're using Python 3, some of these methods may have moved around.

Comment: Yes I am using python 3 but I am just happy to have something to look at. If this works for you surely I can make it work for python3. Thank you very much.